# How to retreive rows from a sql table and display each item in a label in asp.net by using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

i have 5 tables,in every table it has 4 rows. so i need to get all rows and each element in row should be displayed in the table.

But the problem is i wrote all select statements of five tables in one stored proecedures. so how to retrieve them?

Comment: this is not a good practice. please make 5 sprocs , so that your code will be maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve them in a Dataset 
and access each table by 
dataset.tables["TableName or Index"]

**Example:**

```
// SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("ProcedureName","Connection");
// cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
// SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
// Dataset ds=new Dataset();
// da.Fill(ds);
// Now after Filling the Dataset you can Retrieve it by

dataset.tables["TableName or Index"]
```